# python BeautifulSoup getting variables from a garbage page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Folks,
  Trying to grab some variables from a poorly formatted page.

```
html =  response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
links = soup.findAll('a')

for link in links:
    for x in link.attrs:
       print x
```

output:

```
(u'href', u"javascript:Set_Variables('FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME', \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'123456789123', \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'FOOOOOOO',\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'54',\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'2014',\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'BAZZZZ',\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'BARRRRRRRRRR',\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'07/31/2015',\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'')")
(u'onmouseover', u"javascript: return window.status=''")
(u'href', u"javascript:Set_Variables('FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME', \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'123456789123', \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'FOOOOOOO',\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'54',\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'2014',\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'BAZZZZ',\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'BARRRRRRRRRR',\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'07/31/2015',\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'')")
(u'onmouseover', u"javascript: return window.status=''")
```

***Question***:
How would I grab the `FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME` , `FOOOOOOO`, `BARRRRR`, `BAZZZZZ`, `123456789123` from all this mess?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you only need to focus on the `href` attributes here.

Take everything between the parentheses, split on whitespace and remove the comma and quotes:

```
args = link['href'].partition('(')[-1].rpartition(')')[0]
args = [v.rstrip(',').strip("'") for v in args.split()]
```

Demo:

```
>>> href = u"javascript:Set_Variables('FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME', \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'123456789123', \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'FOOOOOOO',\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'54',\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'2014',\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'BAZZZZ',\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'BARRRRRRRRRR',\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'07/31/2015',\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'')"
>>> href.partition('(')[-1].rpartition(')')[0]
u"'FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME', \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'123456789123', \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'FOOOOOOO',\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'54',\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'2014',\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'BAZZZZ',\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'BARRRRRRRRRR',\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'07/31/2015',\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t''"
>>> [v.rstrip(',').strip("'") for v in href.partition('(')[-1].rpartition(')')[0].split()]
[u'FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME', u'123456789123', u'FOOOOOOO', u'54', u'2014', u'BAZZZZ', u'BARRRRRRRRRR', u'07/31/2015', u'']
```